# Extract which rows groups appear using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider the following:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(group_1 = c("A", "B", "A", "C"),
                 group_2 = c("B", "C", "B", "A"))

> df
  group_1 group_2
1       A       B
2       B       C
3       A       B
4       C       A
```

I would like to receive the following output, in pseudocode:

```
df %>%
  group_by(group_1, group_2) %>%
  summarize(rows = whichever_rows_contain_group_1_and_group_2, .groups = "keep")

group_1 group_2   rows
      A       B    1,3
      B       C      2
      C       A      4
```

I've tried playing around with `rownames()` with not much luck. What is the appropriate command with `summarize()` that I can use to get what I seek?

The value of `rows`, for each row, should be in ascending order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try working around `row_number()` to create a new variable and then use `summarise()` to obtain the desired variable using `toString()`. Here the code:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
dfnew <- df %>% 
  mutate(id=row_number()) %>%
  group_by(group_1,group_2) %>%
  summarise(Var=toString(id))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   group_1 [3]
  group_1 group_2 Var  
  <fct>   <fct>   <chr>
1 A       B       1, 3 
2 B       C       2    
3 C       A       4
```

Another option can be (Many thanks and all credit to **@ThomasIsCoding**):

```
#Code2
dfnew2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(id=row_number()) %>%
  group_by(group_1,group_2) %>%
  summarise_at("id",toString)
```

Same output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   group_1 [3]
  group_1 group_2 id   
  <fct>   <fct>   <chr>
1 A       B       1, 3 
2 B       C       2    
3 C       A       4
```

Comment: An alternative for you last line might be `summarise_at("id",toString)`. Anyway, liked your answer, +1!

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding You are right! I will update the post with that valious insight!

Answer (score 1):

Try `aggregate` like below

```
aggregate(rows ~ ., cbind(df,rows = 1:nrow(df)),c)
```

which gives

```
  group_1 group_2 rows
1       C       A    4
2       A       B 1, 3
3       B       C    2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` way.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

df %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  group_by(group_1, group_2) %>%
  summarise(rows = paste0(rowid, collapse = ","))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   group_1 [3]
  group_1 group_2 rows 
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>
1 A       B       1,3  
2 B       C       2    
3 C       A       4
```

Answer (score 1):

Using dplyr and paste0

```
> library(dplyr)
> df %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% group_by(group_1, group_2) %>% summarise(rows = paste0(rn, collapse = ','))
`summarise()` regrouping output by 'group_1' (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   group_1 [3]
  group_1 group_2 rows 
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>
1 A       B       1,3  
2 B       C       2    
3 C       A       4    
>
```